Enable/Disable Interrupt for Aarch64 Architecture
I would like to ask how to call a kernel module in C code. I have a question: if I call setup.sh for the project like this, will it execute according to the priority of IRQ numbers?
#insert and make node for checker interrupt module
cd ~/kernel_module/check_interrupt

sudo insmod checkinterrupt.ko

sudo mknod /dev/check_interrupt c 93 0  

# insert and make node for enable interrupt module
cd ~/kernel_module/enable_interrupt

sudo insmod interrupt_en.ko

sudo mknod /dev/enable_interrupt c 94 0

# insert and make node for disale interrupt module
cd ~/kernel_module/disable_interrupt

sudo insmod interrupt_dis.ko

sudo mknod /dev/disable_interrupt c 95 0


This is the GitHub repository for my kernel module.
kernel module
Is it reasonable for me to call the kernel module for processing in C code like this?
#define DEVICE_PATH "/dev/check_interrupt"
bool INTERRUPTS_ENABLED(){
    int fd;
    unsigned long daif_value;
    char buffer[128];

    // Open the device file
    fd = open(DEVICE_PATH, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open device file");
        return false;
    }
    if (read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to read DAIF value");
        close(fd);
        return false;
    }
    if (sscanf(buffer, "DAIF register: 0x%lx", &daif_value) != 1) {
        perror("Failed to parse DAIF value");
        close(fd);
        return false;
    }
    close(fd);
    return !((daif_value >> 7) & 1);
}


#define ENABLE_PATH "/dev/enable_interrupt"

void ENABLE_INTERRUPTS(void) {
    if (!INTERRUPTS_ENABLED()) {
        int fd;
        fd = open(ENABLE_PATH, O_WRONLY);
        if (fd < 0) {
            perror("Failed to open device file");
            return;
        }

        char buffer[1] = {0};
        if (write(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) < 0) {
            perror("Failed to write to device file");
        }

    // Close the device file
        close(fd);
        printf("Interrupt should now be enabled\n");
    }
}

#define DISABLE_PATH "/dev/disable_interrupt"

void DISABLE_INTERRUPTS(void) {
    if (INTERRUPTS_ENABLED()) {
        int fd;
        fd = open(DISABLE_PATH, O_WRONLY);
        if(fd < 0){
            perror("Failed to open device file ");
            return ;
        }
        
        char buffer[1] = {0};
        if(write(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) < 0)){
            perror("Failed to write to device file");
        }
        close(fd);
        printf("Interrupt should now be disable\n");
    }
}

And how can I include those interrupt handlers within a single function? Is my approach reasonable?
   uint8_t buf[2];
   buf[0] = address;
   buf[1] = value;
   
    //char rx[7] = {0, 7};
    
    gpioWrite(_ss, 0);

    DISABLE_INTERRUPTS();
  
    int status = spiXfer(0 ,(char *) buf, (char *)buf , 2) ;
    
    if (status < 0)
        {
            cout << "Cant transfer data" << endl;
        }
    ENABLE_INTERRUPTS();
    gpioWrite(_ss, 1);
    return buf[1];

I don't have experience in handling processes like this, I hope with everyone's experience can help me.

This probably doesn't do what you want at all, because it's completely context-unaware. But even then, it'd generally not reasonable to mask interrupts in EL0 to begin with. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Hi sir. Actually, I just want to enable/disable interrupts and check whether interrupts are activated or not. To do this, I believe I need to access the kernel module to gain privileged access level, as the DAIF register cannot be accessed in user mode. How can I read the DAIF register and write to the DAIFSET and DAIFCLR registers in user mode? If I access it in the kernel module, how can I invoke that kernel module from my C source code?

But that would be like allocating memory in the kernel. It has no meaning for userland. Are you familiar with exception returns and SPSR_EL1?

I don't have any experience with SPSR_EL1. Regarding exception returns, I have some knowledge of the concept, but how can I perform this in user mode, considering the two things you mentioned (SPSR_EL1 and exception returns)?
